# 'my_test' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

Tags: python, error-handling, find, element

1.This is the code of test_loginqq.py:

```
 #coding=utf-8
 from selenium import webdriver
 import time
 class loginout():

def test_login(self,driver):


    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://en.mail.qq.com/cgi-bin/loginpage")
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.switch_to_frame("login_frame")
    driver.find_element_by_id("switcher_plogin").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("u").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("u").send_keys("*****")
    #driver.find_element_by_id("emailTips_0").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("p").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("p").send_keys("****")
    driver.find_element_by_id("login_button").click()
    title=driver.title
    print (title)
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    user=driver.find_element_by_id("useraddr").text
    print user
    print "log in successfully"
    #driver.quit()
def test_logout(self,driver):
    #driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[test()='Sign out']").click()
    title=driver.title
    print title
    driver.quit()
```

2.This is the code of test_main.py:

```
  #coding=utf-8
  from selenium import webdriver
  from test_loginqq import loginout
  import time
  import unittest
      class my_test(unittest.TestCase):
                  def setUp(self):
                      print "test start"
                  def test_test(self):

                      loginout().test_login(self)
                      loginout().test_logout(self)

                  def test_test0(self):
                      a="hello"
                      b="hello world"
                      self.assertIn(a,b,msg='a is not in b')
                 def tearDown(self):
                     print "test end"
 if __name__=='__main__':
      suite=unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(my_test)
      unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

3.When I run the test_main.py,I got an error:'my_test' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath', I have no idea about this, can someone help me with my qustions?

Comment: I used the selenium IDE to record my scripts, when I tried to locate the element "Sign out", I got an error:Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | null | ]]. ...Hope this can be help

Answer (score 0):

you should instantiating the webdriver.Firefox() in loginout class

this code maybe you want:

```
     #coding=utf-8
 from selenium import webdriver
 import time
 class loginout():
   def test_login(self, driver):

    driver.get("https://en.mail.qq.com/cgi-bin/loginpage")
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.switch_to_frame("login_frame")
    driver.find_element_by_id("switcher_plogin").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("u").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("u").send_keys("*****")
    #driver.find_element_by_id("emailTips_0").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("p").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("p").send_keys("****")
    driver.find_element_by_id("login_button").click()
    title=driver.title
    print (title)
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    user=driver.find_element_by_id("useraddr").text
    print user
    print "log in successfully"
    #driver.quit()
def test_logout(self,driver):
    #driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[test()='Sign out']").click()
    title=driver.title
    print title
    driver.quit()

 #coding=utf-8
  from selenium import webdriver
  from test_loginqq import loginout
  import time
  import unittest
      class my_test(unittest.TestCase):
                  def setUp(self):
                      print "test start"
                  def test_test(self):
                      driver = webdriver.Firefox()
                      loginout().test_login(driver)
                      loginout().test_logout(driver)

                  def test_test0(self):
                      a="hello"
                      b="hello world"
                      self.assertIn(a,b,msg='a is not in b')
                 def tearDown(self):
                     print "test end"
 if __name__=='__main__':
      suite=unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(my_test)
      unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Comment: I added the driver=webdriver.Firefox() in lgoinout class, but still the question

Comment: there is the docs: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver  .I think you need instantiating like this :  `driver = webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver() `

Answer (score 0):

you have geckodriver in you computer? If not, download in here: [geckodriver.exe](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), and move the file gecko to C:\Windows\System32. In the environment variable, add geckodriver, so that your computer accepts correctly.